# Better way to create a single iterative unpack function in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table, unpack

Lua unpack funtion works only for simple table, so I though to write a function which can unpack complex tables. It works fine but I am looking for better ways to write such a function. The code is below:

```
c = {1,2,{3,4},{{5,6},{7,8}}}

vt = {}

function convertToSimpleTable(t,vacantTable)

    if type(t)=="table" then

        for _,val in ipairs(t) do

            if type(val)=="table" then
                convertToSimpleTable(val,vacantTable)
            else
                table.insert(vacantTable,val)
            end
        end
        return vacantTable
    else
        return {t}
    end

end

print(unpack(convertToSimpleTable(c,vt)))
```

Output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

For this function to work I need to supply a vacant table because if I initialize a table inside the function it is re initialized as the function is iterative, hence giving wrong results

Comment: just add `vacantTable=vacantTable or {}` in begin of function. Or create second function eg.`convertToSimpleTable_impl` and call this one from basic wrapper `function convertToSimpleTable(t) return convertToSimpleTable_impl(t, {}) end`

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
vacantTable=vacantTable or {}
```

to the beginning of the function. Or create a second function and call this one from basic wrapper:

```
function convertToSimpleTable(t)
  return convertToSimpleTable_impl(t, {})
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
c = {1,2,{3,4},{{5,6},{7,8}}}

function convertToSimpleTable(t)
  local ans = {}
  for _,t in ipairs(t) do
    if type(t) == 'table' then
      for _,t in ipairs(convertToSimpleTable(t)) do
        ans[#ans+1] = t
      end
    else
      ans[#ans+1] = t
    end
  end
  return ans
end

print(unpack(convertToSimpleTable(c)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Special thanks to [Dan200](https://twitter.com/DanTwoHundred) for writing this [fantastic code](http://pastebin.com/X9D9Rtkp).

```
local function serializeImpl( t, tTracking, sIndent )
    local sType = type(t)
    if sType == "table" then
        if tTracking[t] ~= nil then
            error( "Cannot serialize table with recursive entries", 0 )
        end
        tTracking[t] = true

        if next(t) == nil then
            -- Empty tables are simple
            return "{}"
        else
            -- Other tables take more work
            local sResult = "{\n"
            local sSubIndent = sIndent .. "  "
            local tSeen = {}
            for k,v in ipairs(t) do
                tSeen[k] = true
                sResult = sResult .. sSubIndent .. serializeImpl( v, tTracking, sSubIndent ) .. ",\n"
            end
            for k,v in pairs(t) do
                if not tSeen[k] then
                    local sEntry
                    if type(k) == "string" and not g_tLuaKeywords[k] and string.match( k, "^[%a_][%a%d_]*$" ) then
                        sEntry = k .. " = " .. serializeImpl( v, tTracking, sSubIndent ) .. ",\n"
                    else
                        sEntry = "[ " .. serializeImpl( k, tTracking, sSubIndent ) .. " ] = " .. serializeImpl( v, tTracking, sSubIndent ) .. ",\n"
                    end
                    sResult = sResult .. sSubIndent .. sEntry
                end
            end
            sResult = sResult .. sIndent .. "}"
            return sResult
        end

    elseif sType == "string" then
        return string.format( "%q", t )

    elseif sType == "number" or sType == "boolean" or sType == "nil" then
        return tostring(t)

    else
        error( "Cannot serialize type "..sType, 0 )

    end
end

function serialize( t )
    local tTracking = {}
    return serializeImpl( t, tTracking, "" )
end
```

PS: Originally made for a Minecraft mod called Computer Craft, so some functions might not work.